# Django-ajax-selects with AJAX_SELECT_BOOTSTRAP = False

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-ajax-selects

At work we are using `django-admin` webapp. I wanted to implement `django-ajax-selects` functionality to some of fields. Our network is isolated from Internet and I cannot use `django-ajax-selects`'s CDNs. Documentation says that in such case you should set `AJAX_SELECT_BOOTSTRAP` to `False` in `settings.py` file. However, when I set this parameter, `django-ajax-selects` fails to use `django`'s `jquery`.
`Django`'s version is `1.11.10`, `Python2`.

Steps to reproduce my issue:

```
pip install django==1.11.10 django-ajax-selects
django-admin startproject proj ./
python manage.py startapp test_app
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

**test_app/models.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models


class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    something = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class SecondModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**test_app/lookups.py**

```
from ajax_select import register, LookupChannel
from .models import Tag

@register('tags')
class TagsLookup(LookupChannel):

    model = Tag

    def get_query(self, q, request):
        return self.model.objects.filter(name__icontains=q)

    def format_item_display(self, item):
        return u"<span class='tag'>%s</span>" % item.name
```

**test_app/admin.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.contrib import admin
from ajax_select import make_ajax_form
from .models import Tag, SecondModel


@admin.register(Tag)
class TagAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['name', 'something']


@admin.register(SecondModel)
class SecondModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    form = make_ajax_form(SecondModel, {
        'tag': 'tags'
    })
```

**proj/settings.py** - adding the app and `ajax_select` to `INSTALLED_APPS`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'ajax_select',
    'test_app',
)
```

**proj/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from ajax_select import urls as ajax_select_urls

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^ajax_select/', include(ajax_select_urls)),
]
```

Then

```
python manage.py makemigrations test_app
python manage.py migrate
```

If I run the server like that it works absolutely fine (because it uses CDNs to load `jquery` and stuff).
But if I set `AJAX_SELECT_BOOTSTRAP` to `False` I will get a `TypeError` in browser's console and the `ajax` functionality will not work. I guess `ajax_select.js` just loads before `django`'s `jquery` was loaded. I could not figure it out, how can I specify load order or may be there is another way? Template overriding would be not very good idea as there is some overriding already used by other apps and I'm afraid it can cause some conflicts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end what I needed to do was to manually download `jquery.min.js`, `jquery-ui.js`, `jquery-ui.css` and also `jquery-ui images` library, put them into app's `static` directory and point to them in `admin.py`:

**admin.py**

```
...
@admin.register(SecondModel)
class SecondModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = SecondModelForm

    class Media:
        js = ["/static/js/jquery.min.js",
              "/static/js/jquery-ui.js"]
        css = {'all': ["/static/css/jquery-ui.css"]}
```

Also don't forget to run `python manage.py collectstatic` for static files to be copied to common `static` directory.